# How to trigger a function on a value that can change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functions that are triggered when an element is clicked. The elements are stored in an array. But the value that trigger the functions change. Here is the code for the function:

```
// first I store the element of a list in an array
var promo = new Array(),
indexOfTheElement = 3;
$('#list li').each(function(){
    promo.push($(this));
});

$(myArray[indexOfTheElement]).click(function(){
    indexOfTheElement--;
    // Do something
    return false;
});
```

**Edit:** The element of a list are stored in an array, and the function is triggered when you click an element of the list. For example if you click the third element, the function will be triggered, and then it must work when you click the second.

Comment: where does the value for `indexOfTheElement` come from?

Comment: im confused are you wanting to add a click event to an array of elements?

Comment: try naming your callback and then putting `$(myArray[indexOfTheElement]).click(callback_function);` inside of it.

Comment: this could be way shorter by just doing this: `$(#list li).get(indexOfTheElement).click(function(){
    indexOfTheElement--;
    $(this).unbind(click);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be a scope issue, but I believe you want to use bind() and unbind() on each function call.  For instance:

```
var foo = function(){
    myArray[index].unbind("click");
    index--;
    //do something
    myArray[index].bind("click", foo);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you read the comments on your question too--a callback might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to look into .one for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Interesting method.  Every time I think I've seen the coolest parts of jQuery someone proves me wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I didn't know the one() function and it's really great.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you event handler unhook current event handler and set the new one, simply declare the function (not use an anonymous function) when you set the click().

```
$(myArray[indexOfTheElement]).click(doSomething);

function doSomething()
{
 $(myArray[indexOfTheElement]).off("click", doSomething);
 $(myArray[--indexOfTheElement]).click(doSomething);
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `live()` and code inside `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var promo = new Array(),
indexOfTheElement = 3;
$('#list li').each(function(){
    promo.push($(this));
});

$(myArray[indexOfTheElement]).live('click',function(){
    indexOfTheElement--;
    // Do something
    return false;
});


});
```